# Change Epson Cash Drawer setting

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript

I'm looking for a way to change the settings that control the cash drawer either with powershell, vbscript, batch, etc.  We have over 40 stores with several registers each.  All of those receipt printers were originally configured to open the cash drawer before each print.  I have updated our POS software such that it now sends the correct code to prompt the printer to open the drawer only when it is needed (cash transaction, not credit/debit).  I'm looking for a way to update the driver setting for all of these printers without having to manually adjust each one.  The computers are running Windows 7.

I have tried using PowerShell with some combination of Get-Printer and Set-PrinterProperty, but those cmdlets are not available with Windows 7.  I've tried using cscript prncnfg.vbs, but there are no configurable settings options with that command that I could use for this specific settings.

Comment: Ok, I'm genuinely curious.  Why the negative votes?  If you are going to vote down my question, please leave a comment telling me why so that I can improve and hopefully get a resolution to my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only so many places that settings can be saved (Registry, File...). Use [Sysinternal's Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to monitor where the setting is changed.

1. Start the application.
2. Just before you go to configure the setting, start capturing in Process Monitor.
3. Make the change to the setting.
4. Stop capturing in Process Monitor.
5. Filter by the PID or Process Name.
6. Look for write operations to the registry or a file that might represent that setting in your application.
7. Verify the setting by making changes manually and checking in the application GUI.

You can then use batch, Powershell, VBS, DSC, SCCM or whatever to make that change for all of your clients.

Comment: It took a little while to test this out.  Finally was able to test this method using a little help from [serverfault]( http://serverfault.com/questions/341043/process-monitor-fails-to-start-on-a-64-bit-computer)  Unfortunately, the result I found is that changing the cash drawer control settings for the printer results in all the printer settings being stored in the registry in one key as a chunk of binary data. Not very useful for editing via a script

Comment: If the binary doesn't contain unique information there is no reason you can't write that value using a script. Can you copy that binary value to a second computer and it test it?